# Can I use JQ to narrow the json object in an array?

Tags: json, jq

Input:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
        "a": "a1",
        "b": "b1",
        "c": "1"
      },
      {
        "a": "a2",
        "b": "b2",
        "c": "2"
      }
    ]
}
```

Expected output:

```
{"a": "a1", "b": "b1"}
{"a": "a2", "b": "b2"}
```

The closest approach I can get so far is:

```
"a1"
"a2"
"b1"
"b2"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/jq?q=.foo&j=%7B%22foo%22%3A%2042%2C%20%22bar%22%3A%20%22less%20interesting%20data%22%7D)

Checked the document and tried multiple combination include map_values, but can't finger out. I think it should be a prettier useful use case...

If I use:

```
{a: .data[].a, b: .data[].b}
```

The output becomes:

```
{
  "a": "a1",
  "b": "b1"
}
{
  "a": "a1",
  "b": "b2"
}
{
  "a": "a2",
  "b": "b1"
}
{
  "a": "a2",
  "b": "b2"
}
```

obvious not what I want.

Any one can advise on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expand `.data` only once:

```bash
jq -c '.data[] | {a, b}'
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/JAgQyYrSeon)</sup>

Comment: It would help if your answer explains what you are doing

Comment: Yeah agree with @drum, if you can explain or guide me to specific document, that would be great.

Comment: I think it is a [pipe](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/#pipe) usage, first filter out the `.data[]` array, and then filter out `{a, b}` on every single array item.  Just because the demo from the offical document is too simple...

Comment: There must be something wrong with my understanding, so when the json is any array, this demo doesn't work https://jqplay.org/s/pwlisWe5E8Z

Comment: @WayneMao See https://jqplay.org/s/xMwwh8RT08K You need to expand the array first; the filter `{a, b}` expects an object input.

Comment: @WayneMao  My naive understanding of `jq`'s `[]` syntax, is that it will **_emit_** one array element at a time to the stages following `|` - kinda like the javascript `forEach` method for arrays.

Comment: thanks to you two, interesting grammar!